# What are the order of Javascript event loop stack and loading external CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, event-loop

Assume that I having the code as below:

index.css

```
#box {
  width: 1000px;
}
```

index.html

```
<head>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
</head>
<div id="main">
<div id="box">Box</div>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
<script src="index.js"></script>
</div>
```

index.js

```
setTimeout(function(){
  console.log($('#box').width())
}, 500)
```

What is the output of console.log if:

```
CSS is arrived after 500ms(.i.e server slow): 1000 or other? (I think it should be 1000)
CSS is arrived before 500ms: 1000 or other?
```

And more general question:

```
Can the applying of external CSS be happened when event loop of JS is not empty?
```

Comment: `<link>` element loading `css`  can block `javascript` which follows. Can you create plnkr http://plnkr.co to demonstrate `css` requested at `<link>` element not being defined at `javascript` loaded at `<script>` element following `<link>` element within `document`?

Comment: I don't know the answer (and it might depend on the browser) but you could test this by using a scripting language for your CSS and having it add an artificial delay. Or with postman or some similar tool.